# Problem with pipeline in C, Linux OS Programming

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system, pipe

My problem is in line `read(pipe1[0], path1, pathLength1);`
where for some reason variable `path1` has contains additional characters. For example I enter path `"./test.txt"` which contains 10 characters, then send it trough pipe, and this `read()` line of code sets `path1` variable to `"./test.txt"` and then plus some 4 random characters (14 characters total). Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

I found work around by adding terminate character manually, but I still don't know what's the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(){
    int pipe1[2], pid;
    if(pipe(pipe1) < 0)
    {
        printf("Greska prilikom kreiranja datavoda!\n");
        // exit(-1);
    }
    // Parent process
    if(pid = fork() != 0){
    char path[100], key[100];
    printf("Unesite putanju do fajla koji treba otvoriti \n");
    scanf("%s", path);
    printf("Unesite kljucnu rec koju treba traziti u fajlu\n");
    scanf("%s", key);
    printf("Putanja koju ste uneli je: %s, a kljucna rec: %s\n", path, key);
    close(pipe1[0]);
    int pathLength = strlen(path);
    int keyLength = strlen(key);
    write(pipe1[1], &pathLength, sizeof(pathLength));
    write(pipe1[1], &keyLength, sizeof(keyLength));
    write(pipe1[1], path, pathLength);
    write(pipe1[1], key, keyLength);
    wait(NULL);
    close(pipe1[1]);
    }
    // Child Process
    else
    {
        char path1[100], key1[100];
        int pathLength1, keyLength1;
        close(pipe1[1]);
        read(pipe1[0], &pathLength1, sizeof (pathLength1));
        read(pipe1[0], &keyLength1, sizeof (keyLength1));
        read(pipe1[0], path1, pathLength1);
        read(pipe1[0], key1, keyLength1);
        // For some reason strlen(path1) is 14 ?
        path1[pathLength1] = '\0';
        key1[keyLength1] = '\0';
        printf("Proces dete primio put: %s i kljucnu rec: %s\n", path1, key1);
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen(path1, "r");
        if(f == NULL){
            printf("Greska prilikom otvaranja fajla!");
        }
        int i=0;
        while(!feof(f)){
            i++;
            char tmp[500];
            fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), f);
            if(strstr(tmp, key1) != NULL)
                printf("Kljucna rec se nalazi u liniji: %d\n", i);    
        }
        fclose(f);
        close(pipe1[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note 1: `printf("Proces dete primio put: %s i kljucnu rec: %s\n", &path1, key1)`: `&path1` -> `path1`. Side note 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: you are not checking the return value of read

Comment: I have changed &path1 before, just forgot to change it here. Thank you anyway, but the problem remains. So, how should i check return of read, and what would it change ? I am pretty new to this type of programming ?

Comment: @VladaStefanovic yes, the problem remains. _Side notes_ are useful information, but not directly related to your question.

Comment: Re. `"how should i check return of read"`: please refer to the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html#RETURN_VALUE).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to care about the null terminator of your strings.

On the writer side:

- you write the 10 characters of `"./test.txt"`
- you write the `int` containing 10.

On the reader side:

- you read the length (10) into `pathLength1`,
- you read 10 (pathlength1) characters into `path1`. Now `path1` is not a null terminated string because `path1[10]` to `path1[99]` contain undetermined values.

The easiest would be on the writing side change `int pathLength = strlen(path);` to `int pathLength = strlen(path) + 1;`. Then the null terminator will be written into the pipe and will also be read from the pipe on the reader side.

Another method would be to initialize the `path1` buffer to zero, e.g with `memset(path1, 0, sizeof(path1))` or just putting the null terminator at the right place with `path1[pathLength1] = 0`.

Same for `key` and `keyLength`.

Comment: True, i saw that just a few moments before your replay. Thank you a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It's just a simple oversight. I should have done this:

```
int pathLength = strlen(path) + 1;
int keyLength = strlen(key) + 1;
```

because that + 1 accounts for the `'\0'` at the end of the string I am writing through pipeline.